# Remember me functionality using UISwitch and NSUserDefaults ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

I have a view controller which has text fields for username and password. Then below them I've a switch. If the switch is set to ON, then the login details of the user should be auto filled, when the user accesses the application after logging out. 
Here's my code for the switch:

```
-(IBAction)rememberUser:(id)sender
{
    if(rememberMe.on == YES)
    {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* textField1Text = mUserName.text;
    [defaults setObject:textField1Text forKey:@"textField1Text"];

    NSString *textField2Text = mPassword.text;
    [defaults setObject:textField2Text forKey:@"textField2Text"];
    }

}
```

I've added this in viewDidLoad:

```
if(rememberMe.on == YES)
   {
    NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *user = [def stringForKey:@"textField1Text"];

    NSString *pass = [def stringForKey:@"textField2Text"];

    mUserName.text = user;
    mPassword.text = pass;
   }
```

However, after logging out, the username and textfields are blank, even if the switch is on. I'm using both the UISwitch and NSUserDefaults for the first time, hence I'm not sure at what places I'm going wrong. Please help.

Comment: FYI storing password/username directly in NSUserDefaults is dangerous , once you got the right answer try to encrypt it and store it in NSUserDefaults

Comment: shall try that.. thanks for the info..

Comment: do not use NSUSerDefaults.. Use KeyChain... more secure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you synchronize after you setObject. Something like this:

```
-(IBAction)rememberUser:(id)sender
{
    if(rememberMe.on == YES)
    {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* textField1Text = mUserName.text;
    [defaults setObject:textField1Text forKey:@"textField1Text"];

    NSString *textField2Text = mPassword.text;
    [defaults setObject:textField2Text forKey:@"textField2Text"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    }

}
```

synchronize helps to store the data.. More on NSUserDefaults, read this: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others,  you shouldn't use `NSUserDefaults` for sensitive information, use Keychain services.

`UICKeyChainStore` simplifies things.

**Steps:**
1. Download `UICkeyChainStore`
2. Drag h/m files (2) into project
3. Add security framework in build phases
4. Add `UICKeyChainStore.m` to compile sources in build phases
5. Import header files into class as needed

set password:

```
[UICKeyChainStore setString:self.passwordField.text forKey:@"Password"];
```

get password:

```
[UICKeyChainStore stringForKey:@"Password"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding

```
[defaults synchronize];
```

at the end of your if statement inside the rememberUser: method. Adding an object to user defaults does not persist your data, so you have to use the **synchronize** method to do it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to synchronize..

add this line

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:textField2Text forKey:@"textField2Text"];
[defaults synchronize];
```